# Error while executing atlas-create-jira-plugin

Tags: jira-plugin

I am getting this error while executing atlas-create-jira-plugin command, I am starting Jira plugin development:

```
         A new plugin structure is required for JIRA 5 plugins due to significant changes in the APIs.
    Create a plugin for?
    1) JIRA 5
    2) JIRA 4 (or earlier)
    #?1
    Executing: "C:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven\bin\mvn.bat" com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:4.1.6:create

    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Maven Default Project
    [INFO]    task-segment: [com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:4.1.6:create] (aggregator-style)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Downloading: http://www.laughingpanda.org/maven2/org/twdata/maven/maven-cli-plugin-parent/0.7/maven-cli-plugin-parent-0.
    7.pom

    [WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '21a121ae3afd67024dd862f90189be2fb4931146'; remote
    = '<!DOCTYPE' - RETRYING
    Downloading: http://www.laughingpanda.org/maven2/org/twdata/maven/maven-cli-plugin-parent/0.7/maven-cli-plugin-parent-0.
    7.pom

    [WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '21a121ae3afd67024dd862f90189be2fb4931146'; remote
    = '<!DOCTYPE' - IGNORING
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


    Project ID: null:maven-cli-plugin:maven-plugin:0.7

    Reason: Cannot find parent: org.twdata.maven:maven-cli-plugin-parent for project: null:maven-cli-plugin:maven-plugin:0.7
     for project null:maven-cli-plugin:maven-plugin:0.7


    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 16 seconds
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 30 15:43:10 IST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/43M
```

Please let me know how can I proceed.

Thanks,
Rhishi

Comment: I got the issue resolved from this link:                              https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/43851/issue-creating-a-confluence-plug-in-skeleton

Comment: Getting new error while executing atlas-package --

[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
error: error reading C:\Documents and Settings\258866\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\jwebunit\jwebunit-core\2.2\jwebuni
-core-2.2.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: delete the jwebunit folder and try downloading again resolved the issue.